# Filter array of objects by their values

Tags: javascript, lodash

I wish to iterate over an `array` of `objects`, which for purposes of illustration here are `Users`. I would like to filter those `Users` using a search term provided and the value of each of the `objects` properties.

I have come up with the following working solution, however, I am looking to see if anyone has a more elegant method?

```
let users = [
  {
    first_name: "Super",
    last_name: "User"
  },
  {
    first_name: "Admin",
    last_name: "Istrator"
  }
];

function filterObjects(collection, term) {
  let filtered = [];
  _.each(collection, obj => {
    _.forOwn(obj, (value, key) => {
      if (value.includes(term)) {
        filtered.push(obj);
      }
    });
  });

  return filtered;
}

console.log(filterUsers(users, "Su"));
```

**[Edit]**

I make no assumptions about the structure, or the name, or quantity of any fields on the objects, therefore I do not want to use things like `object.field_name === 'something'` for example.

Comment: `var filtered = collection.filter(item => item.first_name.includes(term) && item.last_name.includes(term));`

Comment: @Dementic - Thanks for the response, that will work fine if I know the keys of the object being searched and if there are a limited number.

Comment: As you can see from @Ori Drori's answer, this was the right way. you should always try to consider `how can i use this`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty - Yes, I did. My question was how to improve my functioning solution which I had come up with based on my limited knowledge/Googling of the JS ecosystem. How are any of the answers in the link you provided improvements?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter, and use `_.some()` to iterate the values, and check with `Array.includes()` (or lodash equivalent) if the term exists in the value.

```js
const filterUsers = (collection, term) =>
  collection.filter(o => _.some(o, v => v.includes(term)));

const users = [{"first_name":"Super","last_name":"User"},{"first_name":"Admin","last_name":"Istrator"}];

console.log(filterUsers(users, "Su"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the same idea using [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```js
const { filter, some, includes } = _;

const filterUsers = term => filter(some(includes(term)));

const users = [{"first_name":"Super","last_name":"User"},{"first_name":"Admin","last_name":"Istrator"}];

console.log(filterUsers("Su")(users));
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Wow, seems so straight forward when you know how / what you're looking for. Thanks!